# Set Combobox value using the display value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox whose values are unknown to me. I know only the display values. Without going through the datastore of the combobox and finding the rawvalue-value maps, is there any other easier way to set the combobox by its raw value.

Let's say these are options:

```
 Display: 'A' Value: '1'
 Display: 'B' Value: '2'
 Display: 'C' Value: '3'
```

When I use

```
 Ext.getCmp(comboboxId).setRawValue('A')
```

The above code does set the display value to 'A', but when I checked it's corresponding value, it doesn't change to '1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`findRecordByDisplay`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-findRecordByDisplay) for finding the record:

> Finds the record by searching values in the displayField.

then select it using [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-select):

> Selects an item by a Model, or by a key value.

For example:

```
var cmp = Ext.getCmp(comboboxId),
    record = cmp.findRecordByDisplay('A');

cmp.select(record);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't  need to walk through datastore manually.

```
var record = store.find("field","value");
Ext.getCmp(comboboxId).select(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setValue`  can accept either `valueField` or `displayField` values.  [Link](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-1-0-combobox-setvalue-method.html).

`setRawValue` only sets the 'displayField`. It doesn't call`convert` function or raise any events